# How do I change permission to access all the files recovered through disk recovery tool `test-disk` from a NTFS partition?

Tags: permissions, testdisk

How do I change permission to access all the files recovered through disk recovery tool `test-disk` from two directories on a NTFS partition? I've tried changing permissions through `chmod` and changing owner using `chown` and tried using GUI properties also.

Comment: If the files are on NTFS partition, check if it is mounted read/write not read-only. Also check the permission of the root folder where it is mounted. Try `mount`

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use a LiveCD (I noticed Ubuntu LiveCD still followed file permissions, which is stupid IMO) so I used Kali Linux Live and then it doesn't care about file permissions, copy to External USB or something like that. Or maybe you can change the permissions on the files from inside LiveCD tho im not sure if that works.